# MASM MACRO to select between MACRO and PROC

Tags: nested, macros, masm

I have a piece of asm code I want to use it once as a MACRO and another time as a PROC.

I'm trying the next option.

```
_MACRO_ EQU 1

_START_ MACRO addr
  IFDEF _MACRO_
    &addr& MACRO
  ELSE
    &addr& PROC
  ENDIF
ENDM

_ENDM_ TEXTEQU <ENDM>

_END_ MACRO addr
  IFDEF _MACRO_
    _ENDM_ ; ???
  ELSE
    &addr& ENDP
  ENDIF
ENDM

;------------------------------
; PROC1

_START_ PROC1
......
......
_END_ PROC1
```

Unfortunately I've got the error "fatal error A1008: unmatched macro nesting".

Comment: I wouldn't count on something like this being supported. You're probably better off writing the code as a macro, and then writing a proc that uses the macro.